# setExposureModeLocked does not work for iPhone 11 and above

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, exposure

So, I have an application where I am streaming images and need consistent results across all images even when exposed to bright light(NO AUTO ADJUSTMENTS).

For this I used a AVFoundation as follows:
[device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];

This works great for any model below iPhone 11.
It seems like the newer camera modules do not react the same to the functions called in AVFoundation as the older ones. In these images the first 2 has the flash on and after the flash is turned off.Here is an example of any iPhone below the 11.
[image]

Here is an example of any iPhone 11 and above. [image]

As you can see they do not lock the same way. If anyone has a similar issue please share your experience or comment what you think may help.
Thanks in advance.